# remove item with specific value in winforms listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I want to remove an item in listview where its value is (for example to the pic below) equals to 100109.

[image]

my code is:

```
     private void listy()
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());

        lvi.SubItems.Add(dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(lblD.Text);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(lblV.Text);
        lvi.SubItems.Add("" + dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString() + " x " + quantity.Text + " ");
        lvi.SubItems.Add(unittotal.Text);
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
```

code to remove (which is wrong) is:

```
     foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dgvPOScart.SelectedRows)
        {
            string id = "";
            if (dgvPOScart.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
            {
                int selectedrowindex = dgvPOScart.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

                DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dgvPOScart.Rows[selectedrowindex];

                id = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[0].Value);

                listView1.Items[id].Remove();

            }
    }
```

where id value is 100109.

Comment: This is only the code to add an item, so what have you tried to remove it?  What is your error?

Comment: Why cant you loop through items in listview and check for value if found delete it?

Comment: @jason I only know how to remove item at specific index. Like index 0,1 etc but I want to remove it with specific value like in the question.

Comment: @raj I don't know how sorry that's why I'm asking that

Comment: edited ive included my remove code thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to build a helper function to find the item index you require.

```
private int findIndexForItem(string name)
{
    int ind = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (listView1.Items[i].Text.Equals(name))
        {
            ind = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ind;
}
```

Then call it such as this

```
int ind = findIndexForItem("100109");
if (ind >= 0)
    listView1.Items.RemoveAt(ind);
```

Comment: Exactly what im looking for. Thank you so much sir

Comment: I also suggest looking into using ObjectListView.  http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html  A type of listview which uses objects so you don't have to add items individually.  Although it might not work in this case, but useful for the future.

Answer (score 1):

In order for `listView1.Items[id].Remove();` to work you must set the ListViewItem's Name. See the code below for the required change.

```
private void listy()
{
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    lvi.Name = dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString(); // <---- add this line

    lvi.SubItems.Add(dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add(lblD.Text);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(lblV.Text);
    lvi.SubItems.Add("" + dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString() + " x " + quantity.Text + " ");
    lvi.SubItems.Add(unittotal.Text);
    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir I found the answer but I'll try your method too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following simple way I have putted the loop inside a button event.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem Item in listView1.SelectedItems)
            {
                listView1.Items.Remove(Item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you sir but unfortunately did not resolve the problem. i need to remove and item with specific value. something like. Remove item where item index = ID. (where the value of ID is 100109)